# AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'check_1' - KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to set the checkbox of `id: check_1` to `active: True` after I check if `theme` is equal to `Dark`. but when I try to set the checkbox I get: `AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'check_1'`.

.py file:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class Test(BoxLayout):
    def turn_active_on_theme(self):
        self.check_1.active = True
        pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    theme = 'Dark'

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = self.theme
        if self.theme == "Dark":
            Test.turn_active_on_theme(self)
            pass
        return Test()

MainApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<Test>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDCheckbox:
            group:'group'
            id: check_1
            active: False
        MDCheckbox:
            group:'group'
            id: check_2
            active: False
```

Comment: It's `self.test_2.check_1`, isn't it?

Comment: @TimRoberts No. I was trying to access the checkbox through the id's but that didn't work.

Comment: It's `self.ids.check_1`, actually.